# Как сделать необязательное поле в форме?

Tags: jquery, form

Мне нужно, чтобы при заполнении формы, поле "Примечание"  было необязательным, т.е. можно оставлять пустым. И как вставить картинку в благодарственный текст после отправки формы. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
   function isEmptyObj(obj) {
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        return false;
}

return true;
}

function Order() {
this.orderProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('order')) || {};
this.products = jQuery('.ulwrap', '.row-fluid');
this.loc = jQuery('html').attr('lang').indexOf('ru') != -1 ? 'ru' : 'ua';
this.l_variables = {
    'order' : {
        'ru' : 'Заказать',
        'ua' : 'Замовити'
    },
    'sendButtonText' : {
        'ru' : 'Отправить заказ',
        'ua' : 'Відправити замовлення'
    },
    'cancelButtonText' : {
        'ru' : 'Отменить',
        'ua' : 'Відмінити'
    },
    'addToOrder' : {
        'ru' : 'Добавить к заказу',
        'ua' : 'Додати до замовлення'
    },
    'cart' : {
        'ru' : 'Ваш заказ: ',
        'ua' : 'Ваше замовлення: '
    },
    'cartTotal' : {
        'ru' : 'Стоимость заказа: ',
        'ua' : 'Вартість замовлення: '
    },
    'formTitle' : {
        'ru' : 'Укажите пожалуйста ваши контактные данные',
        'ua' : 'Вкажіть будьласка ваші контактні дані'
    },
    'formDataName' : {
        'ru' : 'Ваше Имя:',
        'ua' : 'Ваше Ім’я:'
    },
    'formDataPhone' : {
        'ru' : 'Контактный телефон:',
        'ua' : 'Контактний телефон'
    },
    'formDataAddress' : {
        'ru' : 'Укажите адресс доставки',
        'ua' : 'Вкажіть адресу доставки'
    },
    'formDataQuantity' : {
        'ru' : 'Укажите количество приборов',
        'ua' : 'Вкажіть кількість приборів'
    },
    'formDataPrim' : {
        'ru' : 'Примечание',
        'ua' : 'Примітка'
    },
    'orderThankYouText' : {
        'ru' : 'Спасибо за ваш заказ! В ближайшее время с вами свяжется наш менеджер для подтверждения заказа.',
        'ua' : 'Дякуємо за ваше замовлення! Найближчим часом вам передзвонить наш менеджер для підтвердження замовлення.'
    }
};  this.linkAdded = false;
this.cartAdded = false;
this.cart = jQuery('<div class="cart" />');
this.addOrderLink();
this.checkOrder();
}

Order.prototype.checkOrder = function() {
if (!isEmptyObj(this.orderProducts) && !this.cartAdded) {
    this.cart.empty();
    jQuery('#headerwrap').append(this.cart);
    this.cart.append('<p>' + this.l_variables.cart[this.loc] + '<span id="orderSumm"></span></p>', '<ul class="cart-list" />');
    this.cartAdded = true;
}
this.updateCart();
};
Order.prototype.placeOrder = function(callback) {
var self = this,
    modalWrap = jQuery('<div id="orderConfirm" />'),
    form = jQuery('<form />'),
    cancelButton = jQuery('<button>' + this.l_variables.cancelButtonText[this.loc] + '</button>');
jQuery('body').append(modalWrap);
modalWrap.append('<h3>' + this.l_variables.formTitle[this.loc] + '</h3>', form);
form.append('<p><input type="text" required name="clientName" placeholder="' + this.l_variables.formDataName[this.loc] + '" /></p>' +
'<p><input type="text" required name="clientPhone" placeholder="' + this.l_variables.formDataPhone[this.loc] + '" /></p>' +
'<p><input type="text" required name="clientAddress" placeholder="' + this.l_variables.formDataAddress[this.loc] + '" /></p>' +
'<p><input type="text" required name="quantity" placeholder="' + this.l_variables.formDataQuantity[this.loc] + '" /></p>' +
'<p><input type="text" required name="prim" placeholder="' + this.l_variables.formDataPrim[this.loc] + '" /></p>' +
'<button type="submit">' + this.l_variables.sendButtonText[this.loc] + '</button>', cancelButton);
form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pr = '', j = 0;
    jQuery.each(self.orderProducts, function() {
        pr += this.name + '^' + this.price + '^' + this.count + '~';
        j++;
    });
    callback(pr, form.serialize());
});
cancelButton.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modalWrap.remove();
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

параметр "required" означает что поле обязательно для заполнения уберите его и поле перестанет быть обязательным